# Why me recyclerview item automatically click?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am working on an application where i have list of items in recyclerview on items i have a hear icon as wishlist the problem is when i click on the first item the last item automatically selected when i select the second item the second last got selected automatically. I dont know why this is happening?? please guide me

**My RecyclerView Adapter**

public class RecyclerviewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerviewAdapter.Viewholder> {

```
ArrayList<RecyclerviewModel> datalist;
Context context;

public RecyclerviewAdapter(ArrayList<RecyclerviewModel> datalist, Context context) {
    this.datalist = datalist;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View viewholder = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent , false);
     return new Viewholder(viewholder);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Viewholder holder, int position)
{
    holder.name.setText(datalist.get(position).getName());
    holder.email.setText(datalist.get(position).getEmail());
    holder.desc.setText(datalist.get(position).getDesc());
    holder.book.setText(datalist.get(position).getBook());

    //code for setting image-slider on home
    holder.sliderAdapterExample = new SliderAdapterExample(context.getApplicationContext(), datalist.get(position).getImages());
    holder.imageSlider.setSliderAdapter(holder.sliderAdapterExample);

    final RecyclerviewModel datawish = datalist.get(position);
    String wishName = datawish.getName();
    String wishEmail = datawish.getEmail();
    

    holder.wishlist.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

            int pos = holder.getBindingAdapterPosition();
            if(compoundButton.isChecked())
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "item added to wishlist" + pos , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {

                Toast.makeText(context, "item removed to wishlist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return datalist.size();
}

public class Viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


    TextView name, email, desc, book;
    SliderView imageSlider;
    SliderAdapterExample sliderAdapterExample;
    CheckBox wishlist;

    public Viewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_name);
        email = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_email);
        desc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_desc);
        book = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_book);
        wishlist = itemView.findViewById(R.id.wishlist_checkbox);
        imageSlider = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

    }
}
```

}

**i click on the first heart icon**

[image: enter description here]

**the last one is automatically clicked**

[image]

Comment: Hi there, can you share your related codes about you problem.?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Ticherhaz asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: i have added the recyclerview code please check

Comment: Why you are using setOnCheckedChangeListener ? Also you can use position from onBindViewHolder() method no need to use this - holder.getBindingAdapterPosition();

Comment: @AdityaNandardhane i am using setoncheckedlistner to check or uncheck the wishlist(heart ) icon

Comment: Have you tried to use the position in the list, and not in the adapter?

Comment: Create boolean property in your POJO class, then when you click on item you set it to true and vice versa. Also use that boolean property to show whether item has been check or not. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Why this happening? Because when you scroll recyclerview remove hidden items automatically. For ex: 0 will be remove when scroll down and 1 item will be 0, 2 item will be 1 and 3->2,4->3 like this. There are 2 ways fix this error:**

**1) Simple way, but this method freeze your app when data is big:**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Viewholder holder, int position)
{
    holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
}
```

**2) If you want you use second method you must add unique_id to your arraylist each item:**

```
public class RecyclerviewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerviewAdapter.Viewholder> {

ArrayList<RecyclerviewModel> datalist;
Context context;
private ArrayList<String> checkedItems=new ArrayList<>();

public RecyclerviewAdapter(ArrayList<RecyclerviewModel> datalist, Context context) {
    this.datalist = datalist;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View viewholder = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent , false);
    return new Viewholder(viewholder);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Viewholder holder, int position)
{
    int pos=holder.getAdapterPosition();
    holder.name.setText(datalist.get(pos).getName());
    holder.email.setText(datalist.get(pos).getEmail());
    holder.desc.setText(datalist.get(pos).getDesc());
    holder.book.setText(datalist.get(pos).getBook());

    //code for setting image-slider on home
    holder.sliderAdapterExample = new SliderAdapterExample(context.getApplicationContext(), datalist.get(pos).getImages());
    holder.imageSlider.setSliderAdapter(holder.sliderAdapterExample);

    final RecyclerviewModel datawish = datalist.get(pos);
    String wishName = datawish.getName();
    String wishEmail = datawish.getEmail();


    holder.wishlist.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if(b){
                checkedItems.add(datalist.get(pos).getUniqueId());
            } else {
                checkedItems.remove(datalist.get(pos).getUniqueId());
            }
        }
    });
    
    // Check your selection here
    if(checkedItems.contains(datalist.get(pos).getUniqueId())){
        holder.wishlist.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        holder.wishlist.setChecked(false);
    }

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return datalist.size();
}

public class Viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


    TextView name, email, desc, book;
    SliderView imageSlider;
    SliderAdapterExample sliderAdapterExample;
    CheckBox wishlist;

    public Viewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_name);
        email = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_email);
        desc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_desc);
        book = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_book);
        wishlist = itemView.findViewById(R.id.wishlist_checkbox);
        imageSlider = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call your Adapter in your Fragment or Activity, add this line before setAdapter()

```
recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(mData.size());
```